# $.scrollTo in IE 8 using class indentifiers and horizontal scrolling

Tags: jquery, class, internet-explorer-8

I've looked at the past questions and just can't find exactly what I'm looking for.
My code work as intended in firefox but in IE 8 it doesn't. The code in question is:

```
 $(window).load(function () {
         if ($.getURLParam("gotoTeam") != null) {
             var param1 = '#' + $.getURLParam("gotoTeam");
             $.scrollTo(param1, 900);

         }
```

}

In IE it scrolls down to the element, but the horizontal scroll bar goes to the right, pushing the middle content area to the extreme left. The intention is that the scroll should only go down vetically, and there should be no horizontal scrolling.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got it working in IE 8 by using the code below:

```
$.scrollTo(param1, {duration: 800, axis: "y"});
```

Comment: consider marking this answer as "accepted" by clicking the "tick" or "check" icon next to it